# React lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle

I use this to method to work with component, the componentWillMount to initialize data for homepage and the componentWillReceiveProps when router change (category page), but when I come back home page from category page, I know because componentWillMount just do one time so I cannot see data.

```
componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchBooks(1)
    }
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.match.params.id && nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id){
            this.props.fetchBookByCategory(nextProps.match.params.id)
        } 
    }
```

I put this initialized code to componentWillReceiveProps, It works but It calls the fetchBooks(1) constantly eventhough I tried to do with some condition, please help me this problems, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set nextProps to this.props on componentWillReceiveProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.match.params.id && nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id){
            this.props.fetchBookByCategory(nextProps.match.params.id)
 this.props = nextProps;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Never do fetching in `componentWillMount` or the `constructor`. instead do it in `componentDidMount`.

[componentWillMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount):

> componentWillMount() is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before render(), therefore setting state synchronously in
>   this method will not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any
>   side-effects or subscriptions in this method.

[componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is
>   mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you
>   need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to
>   instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will
>   trigger a re-rendering.

You can conditionally render your page if data wasn't received yet.

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {
        data.length > 0 ? 
        <List items={data} /> : 
        <div>Loading...</div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you!, with the code I posted, componentDidMount and WillMount call only first time I render homepage, when I change router from other page It cannot show data, I tried re-fetch for home page in componentWillReceiveProps, It works but It fetch Data many, many time, constantly

Comment: when you re-render your component then `componentDidMount` should be called again.